# Flex Slider Last Slide Not Woking/Showing full Image

Tags: javascript

I have used Flex Slider From http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html 
and in this slider The Last Slide Not showing Full width of the Image.
Same when we navigate the slider up to the last image 
then the current first slide not showing prperly.

Need Help..

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the itemMargin where you included the script below:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });
```